# How to print an integer stored as void * in C?

Tags: c, pointers, printing, int, void

I have stored an int in a void * variable in a struct

```
void * data = &ID;
```

and now I want to print it. How would I do this? I tried to dereference it but the compiler complained about dereferencing void*. Thanks!

Comment: `*(int*)data`, if initial type was int.

Comment: show the code you are using to deference it

Comment: http://ideone.com/2wqC8e

Comment: clarify whether `ID` is the `int` you are talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast `data` to `int *` first, then derefer it:

```
printf("%d\n", *(int *)data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to typecast your void* to int* first. Then you need to print value of that pointer means need to dereference it.

```
printf("Data: %d\n", *((int *)data));
```

Answer (score 0):

ya just cast and dereference

```
printf("%d\n", *(int *)data);
```